# spinner.gif loads at second or more click with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to load a gif image before the success is committed on click event, but the image loads only at second or third or more click happening but not at the first time. Why is that? I’ve tried using beforeSend() & also tried out loading the image before ajax call (placing it before $.ajax function). but the same thing is happening. Success() works just as expected.
the js code is:

```
    $('.gal').on('click', function(){
//$(‘#gallery').prepend('<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8887/img/spinner.gif" class="spinner">');//load img
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:8887/image gallery.html",
        beforeSend:function(){
        $('#gallery').prepend('<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8887/img/spinner.gif" class="spinner">');//load img
        },success:function(response){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.container').append($(response)).slideDown();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#gallery').position().top},500);
            },2200);
                    },
        complete:function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#gallery').children('img:first-of-type').remove();
            },2000);}});
});
```

What’s wrong here? suggestion please.

Comment: does ` $('#gallery')` exists when you are prepending to it ? can you simply add the gif in your page and hide it.

Comment: Thanks @Niladri....#gallery itself loads after ajax call, so now including it in the calling html solves the problem.

Comment: it's always better to have it in html

Answer (score 0):

Try $('.gal').first().on({}) and then your onclick event

Comment: I think it can't help because I had problems with loading the spinner at the correct moment & nothing about .gal which just triggers the ajax call...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#gallery').append('<img id="my_spinner" src="http://127.0.0.1:8887/img/spinner.gif">');>   
 $('#my_spinner').on('load', function(){
     $.ajax({
      //..............load data
     });
     $('#my_spinner').remove();
 });
```

Comment: #gallery is under the ajax file so it must be loaded after a successful ajax response, so I cannot use it beforehand...